# How can I prevent CKEditor from wrapping Mura Tags with a paragraph or div?

Tags: ckeditor, mura

How can I prevent CKEditor from messing with Mura Tags? OR how can I get CKEditor to ignore **[m]something here[/m]**?

I have zero experience with modifying CKEditor, but all of the solutions I've seen thus far are usually "ignore this html element" or "allow this html element", whereas this issue is for a particular set of characters.

If I use the following custom Mura Tag within the Mura CMS content editor:

```
[m]$.dspFooter()[/m]
```

I want the output html to be, for example:

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <nav class="nav">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<footer>
```

The actual output is:

```
<p></p>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <nav class="nav">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<footer>
<p></p>
```

Having the Mura Tag wrap with a `<div>` is also unacceptable for my needs:

```
<div>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <nav class="nav">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<footer>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Apologies if I've missed an applicable solution.

Comment: This is a bit of a hack but I think it works. Normally when you add content in the editor it will wrap as you are seeing. If you go into the source code view by clicking the "Source" button you can see and edit the extra tags. Delete the wrapping `<p>` and `</p>` tags then click the "Publish" button to save the changes. NOTE, do not leave the source code view when clicking the publish button. If you ever go back and edit this page in the future it will put the wrapping tags back in so be aware of that also.

Comment: @Miguel-F I've noticed that aspect and it feels like a problematic maintenance "gotcha" to me. There will be multiple Mura Tags sprinkled throughout a single page. I don't want to require users (of varying levels of technical ability) to remember to do this on every page edit. That seems like unnecessary overhead to me.

Comment: Yep, totally agree. I didn't know if you were talking about one-off pages here and there that don't change much or something else. This is definitely not a solution for pages with non-technical folks editing them.